# Retrieve Users from a List of IDs and display them in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new on Flutter, working on a basic social media app using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zR09Snp4TSM&ab_channel=DevMo). Every post has a list stored on Firestore that contains userId of users who liked that post. Now I want to use this list to query for users in users collection and display the users who liked, as it happens in every other social media. Trying to use the UserResult class from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z2Wqm8waSM&ab_channel=DevMo) video of the same tutorial to display the likes. How should I get the UserResults from the list and display them?

I made the following function to build likes.

```
buildLikes() {

Future<QuerySnapshot> users=usersRef.where(usersRef.id, arrayContains: likes ).getDocuments();
print(users);
return FutureBuilder(
  future: users,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return circularProgress();
    }
    List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
      User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
      UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
      searchResults.add(searchResult);
    });
    return ListView(
      children: searchResults,
    );
  },
);
```

}

It is being called as

```
Row(
           children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap:()=> Navigator.push(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context)=>buildLikes()                       
                  )
                ),
              
              
              child: Icon(
                Icons.account_tree_rounded,
                size: 28.0,
                color: Colors.blue[900],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              likesCount.toString(),
            ),
          ],
         ),
```

In buildPostFooter() build function of post model.

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 isLiked = likes[currentUserId] == true;
 print(isLiked);
 print("Building widget");

return Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
     buildPostHeader(),
     buildPostBody(),
     buildPostFooter(),
  ],

);


}
```

This method does not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can query your FirebaseFirestore instance like on this [link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying). Then you can use the map function to convert them into UserResults. As you're not sharing any code, it is hard to give any further clarification.